# linq-to-sql grouping with timezone

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq-to-sql query that groups results by DateTime, something like this:

```
var TheQuery = from ....
               where ....
               group a by a.TheDateTime.Date in TheGroups
```

The problem is that this groups by actual dates that are stored in UTC in the DB. Let's say that I want to group by dates based on the user's timezone. So for instance, if he's in the PST timezone, group by "UTC minus 8 hours", or whatever other offset.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting all the information back anyway, I'd frankly bring it back to the client and do the grouping in LINQ to Objects. That way you can concentrate on using *one* platform's date and time API - it's hard enough using one API correctly when it comes to time zones, let alone two.

(As an aside and a plug, it also means you can use whatever .NET API you like for this - such as [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) ;)

So I'd put all the filtering and projection you can do before the grouping, then use `AsEnumerable()` to force the rest of the execution to occur locally.

Don't forget that you almost certainly can't just add or subtract 8 hours, unless the user is *really* in a time zone which doesn't use daylight saving time (and hasn't historically). Are you also sure that it's appropriate to apply the same time zone to all the data? (It may well - just checking.)

Comment: At the moment, I'm not bringing back all the info from the server; I'm doing the grouping (and counting) on the server and bringing back just the count of each group. I thought of adding a.TheDateTime.AddMinutes(OffsetTimezone) where OffsetTimezone is an int that contains the number of minutes between the UTC and the timezone. It's not underlined red but I haven't compiled the solution yet. Will let you know if this trick works.

Comment: @frenchie: But most time zones don't *have* a fixed offset from UTC - it depends on whether daylight saving time is active or not.

Comment: Yes, I calculate the offset every time when the user logs in, using the TimeZoneInfo class, and store it in the session. That way I handle the daylight saving issue.

Comment: @frenchie: No, daylight saving doesn't work that way. Just because the offset might be 8 hours *now* doesn't mean it was 8 hours at `a.TheDateTime.Date`.

Comment: I decided to go with what I have since the app will be used for professional purposes; it's unlikely that people will be working in the night so the day light saving issue shouldn't be a problem.